# Integration testing of my app that uses RTK Query to get/update data from/to firebase. I am using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I need help in testing my food ordering app that uses RTK Query to get/update data from/to firebase. I am stuck as I am not sure if I can wrap my actual redux store that has reducers(RTK Query) while rendering my cart component in testing.

```
export const api = createApi({
    baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
    reducerPath: 'api',
    tagTypes: ['GetCartItems'],
    endpoints: (build) => ({
        getCartItems: build.query<"notExists" | GetCartItemsReturn, string>({
            async queryFn(user) {
                try {
                    const cartDocRef = doc(db, `cart/${user}`)

 .......and other endpoints that have updateDoc, getDoc, setDoc (firebase queries)
export const { useUpdateCartMutation, useGetCartItemsQuery, useDeleteCartItemMutation } = api
```

getCartItems returns an object that has restaurantId and the itemIds with their quantity
updateCartItems updated the firebase and returns 'success'/error
deleteCartItem deletes the object in firebase

here is my store

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { api } from "../RTKQuery/cartQuery";
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const appStore = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
        return getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: false,
        }).concat(api.middleware)
    },
})

export const store = appStore

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export const useTypedSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

```
cart.tsx

const Cart = () => {
    const { user } = useContext(userContext)
    const { setUserLoginOrSignup } = useContext(loginOrSignUpContext)
    const [updateCart] = useUpdateCartMutation()
    const [deleteCart] = useDeleteCartItemMutation()
    const { data: cartItem } = useGetCartItemsQuery(user?.uid!)
    let restId = ''
    let cartItemSet = new Set<string>()
    console.log('in cart data:cartItem', cartItem)
    if (cartItem === undefined || cartItem === 'notExists') {
        console.log('cartItem data is either undefined or doesnt exist', cartItem)
    } else {
        console.log('cartItem', cartItem)
        restId = cartItem.restaurantId
    }
    const { data, isLoading } = useRestaurantInfo(restId) // this is an api call made to get restaurant info based on the restaurant id returned from firebase

    const handleDecreament = async (itemId: string, price: number) => {

   // this is part of my handleDecreament function that uses deleteCart and updateCart to update/delete cart items in firebase
   if (Object.entries(cartItem.itemWithQuantity).length === 1) {
          cartItemSet.delete(itemId)
          await deleteCart(user?.uid)
    } else
          await updateCart(cartData)
```

I can provide more details/git hub repo link.

I tried the below helpers.tsx but I am not sure how do I use this in testing. I am also getting the error below for this code. Is this the right approach to test?

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import { render as rtlRender } from "@testing-library/react";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";
import { api } from "../../RTKQuery/cartQuery";
import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import type { PreloadedState } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { RootState } from "../../store/appStore";

type preloadState = PreloadedState<RootState>;

const initalState = {
    api: {
      restaurantId: '737440',
      itemWithQuantity: {
        127533210: 1
      },
      queries: {}, // Add empty objects for missing properties
      mutations: {},
      provided: {},
      subscriptions: {},
      config: {}
    }
  };
  

function render(
    ui: React.ReactElement,
    {
        preloadedState = {} as preloadState,
        store = configureStore({
            reducer: {
                [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer,
            },
            preloadedState,
            middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
                getDefaultMiddleware().concat(api.middleware),
        }),
        ...renderOptions
    } = {}
) {
    setupListeners(store.dispatch);

    function Wrapper({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>): JSX.Element {
        const history = createMemoryHistory();

        return (
            <Provider store={store} >
                {children}
            </Provider>
        )
    }

    store.dispatch(api.util.resetApiState());

    return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions });
}

export * from "@testing-library/react";
export { render };
```

error:

> 'preloadedState' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.ts(7022)
> (parameter) preloadedState: any

Answer (score 0):

It is good to have a new clean store for every test. You also want that store to be as similar to your real store as possible. And you don't want to have to configure it in every test file. So I would recommend wrapping your configureStore method in store.ts inside a createStore function and exposing that for your tests:

```
export function createStore() {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: {
      [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer,
    },
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => {
      return getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: false,
      }).concat(api.middleware);
    },
  });
}
export const store = createStore();
```

In your tests you can then import your createStore and create a new store for every test with `const testStore = createStore();` that is identical to your actual store, and has nothing in it. You won't need to reset the state and you can use testStore.dispatch() to set specific data if you need it for a test. you might need to wrap those like this:

```
await act(async ()=> {
  testStore.dispatch(someInfo);
});
```

To make sure everything is set before the actual test starts.

Your error is a typeError because you had you preloadedState added incorrectly, I think what you want is this. You don't need the `as`:

```
    {
        store = configureStore({
            reducer: {
                [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer,
            },
            preloadedState: {}, // I think you want to use your initialState here. 
            middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
                getDefaultMiddleware().concat(api.middleware),
        }),
        ...renderOptions
    } = {}
```

By the way, I believe it is convention to start types with capitals, to distinguish them from the actual values. Right now it is hard to spot the difference between preloadState and preloadedState.

I would only do this if you need to set a lot of preloadedData for a lot of tests, otherwise I would just start with an empty store.
Also it might be interesting to look into using msw for your unit tests of rtkq or using an e2e framework to do full e2e/integration tests.